# A question on polynomials with integral coefficients.

Tags: polynomials

I was solving a particular problem (not necessary here) when the following came to my mind.

Prove or disprove the statement:

If $P(x)$ be a polynomial such that $P(n) \in Z$ $ \forall  n \in Z$ (Z denotes set of integers), then all coeffcients of $P(x)$ are integers.

Is this statement true? I haven't seen this proved ordisproved anywhere. Igot a feeling this may be false but no evidence.

Comment: For instance, $\frac{1}{30}n^5 - \frac{1}{30}n$ is always an integer.

Comment: More generally, fix any $k\ge 0$ and consider the function $n \mapsto {n \choose k}$.  It's a polynomial that always takes integer values, but for $k>1$ the coefficients are not (all) integers.  In a certain sense these are the only examples, as all other examples can be built by adding these together in various ways.

Answer (score 2):

**A simple counterexample?**

---

Note that for a natural number $n$ the polynomial $$\binom {X}{n} =\frac {X (X-1)\cdots (X-n+1)}{n (n-1)\cdots 1}$$ takes integer values at all integers although it does not have integer coefficients.

---

Also see [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/polys.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjj4aSd-azRAhXKqo8KHSdGAaEQFghIMAU&usg=AFQjCNFWAJ6ulXKrxkAEv-eY7Gv3uraPHQ&sig2=IitHjI8KczdEspJUsOJGfA). Hope it helps.

Comment: (except when $n=1$)